# How to run hdparm on boot in Slackware linux?

Tags: slackware, hdparm

My questions are about running hdparm on boot I have following `/etc/hdparm.conf` file:

```
/dev/sda {
    apm = 255
    spindown_time = 0
}
```

- So, how I can specify hdparm to use this settings from the file?
- How to run it on the boot time as earlier as it possible without further rewriting this configuration? For example, with another APM management tool like some kde app.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the easiest solution would be to put the call to `hdparm` in `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`.

`/etc/rc.d/rc.local` is called before the Window manager (eg. KDE) is even started. As your configuration file is located at the default location where `hdparm` looks, this should work fine.